# Cannot find wireless interface on my Kali Linux hosted by virtualbox despite detected and filtering by USB

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Currently using:

```
Virtualbox 6.1
Kali Linux 2021.2 amd64
Alfa AWUS036ACH (chipset: RTL8812AU)
```

The wireless adapter was up and running after installing the drivers from aircrack-ng github repository, specifically for the RTL8812au drivers.

This is the current output of various commands to help diagnose the problem.

$ dkms status

```
realtek-rtl8814au, 5.8.5.1~git20210331.bdf80b5, 5.10.0-kali9-amd64, x86_64: installed
```

```
└─$ iwconfig  
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

lsusb does appear to detect Realtek RTL8812AU.

```
└─$ sudo lsusb                       
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However, there appears to be no wlan0 that exists for the wireless adapter:

```
└─$ ip a    
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:0e:34:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 85712sec preferred_lft 85712sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe0e:348d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
└─$ uname -r                                                                                                          1 ⨯
5.10.0-kali9-amd64
```

[image: USB set to 3.0 with USB filtering on the device already]

Comment: You need to load the driver through `modprobe` command.

Comment: @GAD3R when i used sudo modprobe 8812au theres a fatal error and says its not found

interestingly, sudo modprobe 8814au appears to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Wi-Fi driver from [here](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install git build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl* 
DRV_NAME=rtl8812AU
DRV_VERSION=5.6.4.2
sudo mkdir /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
git archive v${DRV_VERSION} | sudo tar -x -C /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms add -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms install -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
sudo modprobe -v 8812au
```

Comment: will try immediately, the instructions i followed were definitely different from yours, considering when I modprobed for rtl8812au nothing appeared, but modprobe for rtl8814au and its there's for some reason

Comment: not sure why it was working before, but suddenly stopped working now

Comment: @Wickerman see my edit